# Setter doesn't work with -=, +=, etc?

Tags: ruby

I don't understand why I get a nil error. I created the setter properly. But it does not accept -=, +=, or itself behind the = operator. Why?

```
class Test
  def var; @var || 0; end
  def var=(value)
    @var = value
  end

  def initialize
    @var = 2.4 # Sample value
  end

  def test
    puts var
    var -= 1 # <<< crash: undefined method for nil class
    puts var
    var = var - 1 # <<< crash: undefined method for nil class
    puts var
  end
end

a = Test.new
a.test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write as

```
def test
    puts var
    self.var -= 1
    puts var
    self.var = var - 1
    puts var
end
```

If you don't use `self`, then Ruby will treat those `var` as a local variables, rather then `setter` method calls.

Just remember, in Ruby *method call* can never be made without receiver(implicit/explicit). Now if you write `var = 1`, Ruby will treat as [*local variable assignment*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html). But if you write `self.var`, Ruby will parse it as a method call, and will try to call your setter method, if you defined. Also remember `self.var = 1` is a *syntactic sugar* of `self.var=(1)`.

There is more interesting discussion about the same, worth to read [Private setters can be called by self, why not getters?](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4412554)

There is a recent **bug** was found regarding the *private setters*. Here is the [**Bug**](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907) ticket, and it is now fixed too.

Comment: That indeed seems to be the problem. But why do I have to add self in this case? It's within the same class as a method (not static or anything).

Comment: So it's only @var or self.var from within the class itself. I'm more used to C# so that's why I'm so confused I guess. Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: @Napoleon ofcourse `self.var` if you want to call setter method.

Answer (score 0):

Because var is nil. you need to assign some value to it first

```
def test
    puts var
    var=0 
    var -= 1 # <<< crash: undefined method for nil class
    puts var
    var=0
    var = var - 1 # <<< crash: undefined method for nil class
    puts var
  end
```

Comment: "|| 0" should make sure that it returns 0 if it's nil. And the initialize also sets it.

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: It's not clear whether you want an instance variable or a class variable for 'var'.  The example below is for an instance variable.

I would use attr_reader, or attr_accessor if you want to do this external to the class.

```
class Test
   attr_reader :var

   def initialize
      @var=2.4
   end

   def test
     puts @var
     @var -= 1
     puts @var
     @var = @var - 1
     puts @var
   end
end

t=Test.new
t.test
puts t.var

$ /tmp/t.rb
2.4
1.4
0.3999999999999999
0.3999999999999999
```